# Changing from MemoryStream to Stream in C#

Tags: c#

Below is the code where I am passing memory stream and reading it and doing the necessary operation afterwards. Now the requirement has changed and instead of Memory stream, I will be passing Stream and that starts giving me error. I would like to know how can I handle the below method if contents returned here is of Stream type. Now it works fine when my contents is of type MemoryStream.

```
public async Task<string> ReadStream(string containerName, string digestFileName, string fileName, string connectionString)
        {
            string data = string.Empty;
            string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
            var contents = await DownloadBlob(containerName, digestFileName, connectionString);
            if (fileExtension == ".gz")
            {

                using (var unzipper = new GZipStream(contents, CompressionMode.Decompress))
                {
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(unzipper, Encoding.UTF8))
                    {
                        data = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    }

                }
            }
            else
            {                
               data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(contents.ToArray());
            }
            return data;
        }
```

Comment: "*and that starts giving me error*" -- what error?

Comment: Where is the `MemoryStream`? I don't see a `MemoryStream` here... Unless it is the `DownloadBlob`... And even then, it should be transparent. Both `StreamReader` and `GZipStream` work perfectly well with a read-only forward-only `Stream`

Comment: I'm going to downvote this because 1) it's not clear where the `MemoryStream` is (I only know beause I recognised you, and remember your previous question about this bit of code), and 2) you didn't say what the error is or where it's coming from, which are both fundamental parts of an acceptable question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to assume the issue is `contents.ToArray()`, since `Stream` desn't have a `ToArray()` method.

In this case, you'll be better off using a `StreamReader`:

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(contents))
{
    data = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

`StreamReader` uses `Encoding.UTF8` by default, but you can specify it explicitly if you want: `new StreamReader(contents, Encoding.UTF8)`.

You'll note that you're already doing this a few lines above, to read from the `unzipper` stream.